# SHAutoComplete & current working directory?

Tags: windows, winapi

I am using SHAutoComplete with the SHACF_FILESYSTEM option. The problem is, files relative to the current working directory are not autocompleted. There are no suggestions for relative paths -- for example, the working directory contains settings.txt, but I can type "settings" into the edit and nothing appears.

Is there a relatively easy solution? Or do I have to override the autocomplete behaviour with some own lookup?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at the documentation at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776884

You need to explicit specify the "Current directory" as an option. This must be done throu IACList2::SetOptions  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776376

==> You must use the COM interface, to set the options you want... Here is an example:

```
HRESULT EnableAutoComplete(HWND hWndEdit, LPWSTR szCurrentWorkingDirectory = NULL, AUTOCOMPLETELISTOPTIONS acloOptions = ACLO_NONE, AUTOCOMPLETEOPTIONS acoOptions = ACO_AUTOSUGGEST, REFCLSID clsid = CLSID_ACListISF)
{
  IAutoComplete *pac;
  HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_AutoComplete, 
                                NULL, 
                              CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                              IID_PPV_ARGS(&pac));
  if (FAILED(hr))
  {
    return hr;
  }

  IUnknown *punkSource;
  hr = CoCreateInstance(clsid, 
                      NULL, 
                      CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                      IID_PPV_ARGS(&punkSource));
  if (FAILED(hr))
  {
    pac->Release();
    return hr;
  }

  if ( (acloOptions != ACLO_NONE) || (szCurrentWorkingDirectory != NULL) )
  {  
    IACList2 *pal2;
    hr = punkSource->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pal2));
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
      if (acloOptions != ACLO_NONE)
      {
        hr = pal2->SetOptions(acloOptions);
      }

      if (szCurrentWorkingDirectory != NULL)
      {
        ICurrentWorkingDirectory *pcwd;
        hr = pal2->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pcwd));    
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = pcwd->SetDirectory(szCurrentWorkingDirectory);
            pcwd->Release();
        }
      }

      pal2->Release();
    }
  }

  hr = pac->Init(hWndEdit, punkSource, NULL, NULL);

  if (acoOptions != ACO_NONE)
  {
    IAutoComplete2 *pac2;
    hr = pac->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pac2));
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pac2->SetOptions(acoOptions);
        pac2->Release();
    }
  }

  punkSource->Release();
  pac->Release();
}
```

you can call it via:

```
wchar_t szCurDir[MAX_PATH];
GetCurrentDirectoryW(MAX_PATH, szCurDir);
EnableAutoComplete(m_txtBox1.m_hWnd, szCurDir, ACLO_CURRENTDIR);
```

Comment: Thanks much! I am trying it out right now, but I cannot find the IID_PPV_ARGS macro in any of the shell headers. Where exactly is it?

Comment: This is a template starting with Vista... you can replace `IID_PPV_ARGS(&pac)` with `__uuidof(pac), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pac)`.

Comment: You can also define: `#define IID_PPV_ARGS(ppType) __uuidof(**(ppType)), reinterpret_cast<void**>(ppType)` which has the same effect...

Comment: OK I may be doing something wrong but I get GUID not associated errors for IACList2 and ICurrentWorkingDirectory. Is it possible that the GUIDs are defined in some header I forgot to include? (The types themselves are recognized by the compiler though.)

Comment: I hardwired the missing GUIDs in parameters and now it works! Thank you very much!